# dynamically add css class to row

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using SlickGrid and want to add **dynamically** a css class to a row, or cell in a row.

This approach adds the class `highlight` to the column `Name` in row 0:

```
grid.setCellCssStyles("highlight", {
   0 : {
       Name: "highlight",
       }
 });
```

Whereas I want to achieve to set the css class to a row defined in another variable. I tried it as seen below, but it is not working:

```
row = 0;
grid.setCellCssStyles("highlight", {
    row : {
        Name: "highlight",
        }
});
```

Comment: yes. But I think I cannot select the rows with jquery as they have no unique ID set.

Comment: You know the column number and row number, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var row=0;
var obj={};
obj[row]={Name:"highlight"};
grid.setCellCssStyles("highlight",obj);
```

Explanation: When JS reads "row: ..." as a key value pair, it creates a property called row on the object and assigns to that, instead of evaluating the variable row and using its value as the key. This is due to JSON syntax, and I do not know of a way to circumvent this. However, javascript objects are also accessible as associative arrays, which means you can pull the trick I did above: set the (evaluation of row) property of obj to whatever value you require.

Comment: How is that any different to the literal notation?

Comment: Thank you Asad! Could you explain why this works and my first approach did not!?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JGdhX/1/ In JSON, the key is not bounded by quotes or anything. When js reads "row: ..." as a key value pair, it creates a property called row on the object and assigns to that, instead of evaluating the variable row and using its value as the key.